# How can i get an array of images from a collection of nested objects with Lodash?

Tags: json, lodash

```
 {
     "shop": {
         "homebackground": "http://padmenu.s3.amazonaws.com/15/11/2014/05/08/2ec2ff61-d6a0-11e3-8857-10ddb1e6e201.jpg",
         "name": {
             "tr": "My Shop"
         },
         "menus": [{
                 "name": {
                     "en": "Menu"
                 },
                 "children": [{
                     "name": {
                         "en_US": "Category"
                     },
                     "images": [
                         "http://www.progressivedental-ellenlimdds.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/red-wine.jpg"
                     ],
                     "children": [{
                         "name": {
                             "en_US": "Item"
                         },
                         "images": [
                             "http://res.cloudinary.com/finedine/image/upload/c_fill,g_center,h_600/v1435916818/WIne-Bottle_uz03a0.jpg",
                             "http://media.riepenau.com/wines/17973_b.jpg",
                             "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/3",
                             "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/4",
                             "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/5",
                             "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/6",
                             "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/7"
                         ]
                     }]
                 }]
             }]
         }
     }
```

I want to select all the "images" arrays from shop's "children" objects.
How can i do this by using Lodash library?
The output should be an array of consists of image urls:
["url1","url2","url3"]

Comment: Your posted JSON is invalid. please post the correct structure which you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach to solve this problem is by plucking through children and their descendants recursively. The important points are in the `getImages()` function; wherein it flattens all children arrays in one level, pluck each image arrays and compact all items to remove undefined values(caused by children with no images), and then flattening the images array and readied for concatenation. The stopping point of the recursion is when there are no images for the current `children`, returning an empty array. If images are found, then we recursively concatenate all potential descendant images. As to how we get the descendants, we use the same chaining sequence that we used in getting the `images` array but with `children` as the plucking key.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rR6n7B91DVwbYd9HVVI1?p=preview)**

```
function getImages(children) {
  var images = _(children).flatten().pluck('images').compact().flatten().value();
  if(_.isEmpty(images)) {
    return [];
  }
  var descendants = _(children).flatten().pluck('children').compact().flatten().value();
  return images.concat(getImages(descendants));
}

function getShopImages(data) {
  var children = _.pluck(data.shop.menus, 'children');
  return getImages(children);
}

console.log(getShopImages(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pseudo Code

You can solve this with a little bit of recursion:

1. Grab the children list.
2. Extract all the images from the children list with `pluck`.
3. Repeat step 1 with all descendants.
4. Concat all results and flatten.

### Core Code

```
function deepExtract(collection, childKey, property) {
  var exists = _.negate(_.isEmpty);
  var children = _.chain(collection).pluck(childKey).filter(exists).flatten();

  if (_.isEmpty(children.value())) {
    return [];
  }

  var images = children.pluck(property).value();
  var descendantImages = deepExtract(children.value(), childKey, property);

  return _.flatten(images.concat(descendantImages));
};

var tree = _.chain(data).get('shop.menus').value();

var images = deepExtract(tree, 'children', 'images');
```

### Demo

```js
var data = {
  "shop": {
    "homebackground": "http://padmenu.s3.amazonaws.com/15/11/2014/05/08/2ec2ff61-d6a0-11e3-8857-10ddb1e6e201.jpg",
    "name": {
      "tr": "My Shop"
    },
    "menus": [{
      "name": {
        "en": "Menu"
      },
      "children": [{
        "name": {
          "en_US": "Category"
        },
        "images": [
          "http://www.progressivedental-ellenlimdds.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/red-wine.jpg"
        ],
        "children": [{
          "name": {
            "en_US": "Item"
          },
          "images": [
            "http://res.cloudinary.com/finedine/image/upload/c_fill,g_center,h_600/v1435916818/WIne-Bottle_uz03a0.jpg",
            "http://media.riepenau.com/wines/17973_b.jpg",
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/3",
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/4",
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/5",
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/6",
            "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/7"
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

function deepExtract(collection, childKey, property) {
  var exists = _.negate(_.isEmpty);
  var children = _.chain(collection).pluck(childKey).filter(exists).flatten();

  if (_.isEmpty(children.value())) {
    return [];
  }

  var images = children.pluck(property).value();
  var descendantImages = deepExtract(children.value(), childKey, property);

  return _.flatten(images.concat(descendantImages));
};

var tree = _.chain(data).get('shop.menus').value();
log(deepExtract(tree, 'children', 'images'));


// Helper method to output to screen
function log(value) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(value, null, 2) + "\n"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution to my question here:

```
  var children = _(shop.menus[0].children)
    .thru(function(coll) {
        return _.union(coll, _.pluck(coll, 'children'));
    })
    .flatten();

var images = _.chain(children).pluck('images').flattenDeep().compact().uniq().value();
```

The output "images" is an image array.

Comment: Interesting use of `thru`. Quick question, how does this solve the problem if `shop.menus` contains more than one child? Or is it that menu always contains a single element?

Comment: It always contains single element(for now). It is clear that this solution is not as efficient as yours since depending on menus[0] isn't a good way. My solution was temporary today till someone provides a good solution:) @Pete